# Yanking range into register while ignoring blank lines

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, range

I’m trying to yank a range into a register while ignoring blank lines. My range is from line 10 to the end of the file.

```
:10,$v/./"*y
```

Looking at my registers in `:reg` I see that my text is not in the register I specified or any other register. However vim has highlighted all lines not containing a blank line including the first 9 lines.

What am I missing (besides being two bricks shy of a load?)

Comment: You're on the command line. Yanks look like `y[ank] [x]` where `x` is the register (if left out yank goes to default reg). Also, your `vglobal` command is skipping every line that has at least one character. That doesn't sound like your intention. `:help :v`, `:help :yank`

Comment: (cont) Also, if you want to use `:g` or `:v` to yank into a register you need to _append_ to the register by using the uppercase letter not the lowercase letter. (I don't think this can be done with `*` register). `:{range}v/{pattern}/ y X`. If I'm not interpreting your need correctly please update your question with more details.

Comment: `10,$g/./y *` yields the last paragraph into the clipboard and in the "" register.

Comment: Without the global pattern, {range}y * works.

Comment: Because that's a single run of yank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems with your `:vglobal` command and problems with your `:y[ank]`.

First, `:v` runs against lines that *aren't matched* by your pattern. You are skipping all lines with at least one character.

Second, `:g` and `:v` work by running the following command *for each line that they match/don't match*. That means yank is running multiple times and each time it does it overwrites the register. You need to *append* to the register. The way you do that is by using the uppercase form of the register name, not the lower case. That also means you can't use non-letter registers like `*`.

Third, your yank is not correct. You're trying to yank as if you are in Normal mode. But you're on the command line. You need to use the form `:y[ank] [x]` where `x` is the name of a register.

So the actual command needs to be something like:

```
:{range}[gv]/{pattern}/ y [A-Z]
```

More specifically, based on your use case and assuming register `a`...

```
:10,$g/./ y A
```

Don't forget to clear register `a` before you run this since you're appending.

**Update:** Since you really want the yanked text to go into the `*` register there are two alternatives:

1. After the `:g` command runs just do `:let @* = @a`.
2. Use this `:10,$g/./ yank a | let @* .= @a`

The second one runs as a single `:g` command; each time a matched line is found it is yanked into register `a` and then *that* is appended to `*` using the operator `.=` which gives us the equivalent to `let @* = @* . @a`. IOW, we don't need `A` in this case.

Comment: Thank you!. You said, "That also means you can't use non-letter registers like `*`." Since my goal is to get my text into the system clipboard, does that mean I'm out of luck?

Comment: You're welcome. After the `:g` command runs you can copy contents of the letter register to `*` with `:let @* = @a`, for example.

Comment: Actually, I think `:g/…/yank A | let …` updates the register for every line (iow bar is part of global, and you need exec around the global to make it not). I would write two commands if I was worried about performance lag though.

Comment: It works either way but I should have left it as I had it originally: two separate commands.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `:global` which doesn't overwrite a lettered register is to do this with vimscript calls:

```
:call getline(10, '$')->filter({_, v->strlen(v)})->setreg('*')
```

You could take this as the basis for abstracting this into a command which copies all non-blank lines from the specified line (or current if not specified) to the end of the file to the clipboard:

```
function! CpNonblank(...)
    let start = a:0 > 0 ? a:1 : '.'
    call getline(start, '$')->filter({_, v->strlen(v)})->setreg('*')
endfunction
command! -nargs=? CpNonblank call CpNonblank(<args>)
```

So that `:CpNonblank` copies from the current line to the end, and `:CpNonblank 10` copies from line 10 to the end.

(Meta-fact: I prototyped this in vim and then used the function to copy the file)